# How to strip file contents into a list in python and chart using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a text file which contains the following information with each entry on a single line:

```
    Rent: 500
    Gas: 60
    Food: 200
    Clothing: 100
    Vehicle Costs: 100
    Entertainment: 200
    Utilities: 200
    Other Misc: 150
```

My task is to Write a Python program that records the data from the file and uses matplotlib to plot a pie chart showing how you spend your money. I am having trouble with how to strip the value off of the text. Here is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib
import os
def main ():
    infile = open('expenses.txt', 'r')
    cost = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()
    cost = []
    cost_val = line.strip().split() 
    scores.appendint(int(score_val))   
    values = values.split('\n')
    values= [int(i) for i in values]
    print(values)
```

I am getting this error:

> NameError: name 'line' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please limit yourself to one question per thread. I'll just provide some help for the first part, the one for which you provided your attempt.

This is a step-by-step explanation:

```
import matplotlib
import os # you don't actually need this

def main():
    # it is good practice to use `with open as`
    with open('expenses.txt', 'r') as f:
        # read all lines and store them in a list
        lines = f.readlines()
        d = dict()
        for line in lines:
            # create a dictionary entry for every line
            line = line.strip() 
            key, value = line.split(':')[0], int(line.split(':')[1])
            d[key] = value
        expenses, costs = d.keys(), d.values()
        print(expenses) # prints ['Rent', 'Gas', ...]
        print(costs)    # prints [500, 60, ...]
        # now you can plot
main()
```